# How to use createSelector with parameter and Typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, reselect

I use `redux-toolkit` to [generate selectors](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#using-selectors-with-createentityadapter). I want to use them in my own custom `reselect` selectors with parameters. But I do not know how to type the return type of my selector?

```
const selectOrganizationName = (id: string): ??? =>
  createSelector(
    [(state: RootState) => organizationSelectors.selectById(state, id)],
    organization => organization.name
  );

export default selectOrganizationName;
```

```
Missing return type on function.eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Keep in mind that this warning only appears due to your ESLint settings which require explicit return types. Typescript is able to infer the type properly.

When you call the `selectOrganizationName` function, you return a selector that takes a `RootState` and returns an organization name which is `string | undefined`.

```
type Return = (state: RootState) => string | undefined;

const selectOrganizationName = (id: string): Return =>
  createSelector(
    [(state: RootState) => organizationSelectors.selectById(state, id)],
    (organization) => organization?.name
  );
```

However you likely have lots of selectors that you want to create return types for, so you can create a helper type that includes your `RootState` automatically and just requires you to set the type of the selection.

```
type Selector<S> = (state: RootState) => S;

const selectOrganizationName = (id: string): Selector<string | undefined> =>
  createSelector(
    [(state: RootState) => organizationSelectors.selectById(state, id)],
    (organization) => organization?.name
  );
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mbkGbW)

Comment: This answer will result in select running every time component re-renders. For parameterized use-case make pattern is a better approach https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data

Comment: What if my selector has arguments?

Comment: @jayarjo if your selector has arguments then it breaks the rules of selectors

Comment: What are the rules of selectors?

Answer (score 1):

For me as soon as I added a selector for a custom param, it broke the TS of the entire file (all the selectors return types became `any`).

```
export const mappedFavouritesSelector = createSelector(
  // ...Other selectors...
  (_, hkSpotEnabled) => hkSpotEnabled,
  (
    // ...Other selector results...
    hkSpotEnabled,
  )
```

But the issue went away when I pulled out the param selector to a const function ‍♂️:

```
const hkSpotEnabledSelector = (_: RootState, hkSpotEnabled: boolean) =>
  hkSpotEnabled;

export const mappedFavouritesSelector = createSelector(
  // ...Other selectors...
  hkSpotEnabledSelector,
  (
    // ...Other selector results...
    hkSpotEnabled,
  )
```